# Trouble creating a CSS 3d-scene using perspective

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a 3d-scene in css, but I can't seem to get it to work the way I want. What I'm trying to make is a table containing a deck of cards. My HTML looks as folows: (here the 'scene' div is the table and the 'item' is the deck of cards)

```
<div class="scene-wrap">
  <div class="scene">

    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__right">
      </div>
      <div class="item__front">
      </div>
      <div class="item__top">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The item is missing a left and back side, but that's not important at this point. I've made a fiddle here, with the CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/do76ro22/

The problem is that the item element doesn't look realistic, as if the perspective is incorrect. The left border is diagonal but should be straight, to make it look like a real scene. You can see it better if you change the rotateX value on the scene class.

Does anyone know how to make this look more realistic?

Answer (score 0):

probably the property that you are lookin for is

```
perspective-origin: left center;
```

I have added a little left positioning so that it doesn't collapse

```css
.scene-wrap {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  perspective: 800px;
  perspective-origin: left center;
}

.scene {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(50deg);
  position: absolute;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  left: 5px
}

.item__right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.item__front {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform-origin: center top;
}

.item__top {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: darkblue;
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene-wrap">
  <div class="scene">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__right">
      </div>
      <div class="item__front">
      </div>
      <div class="item__top">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```